# How do I persist data returned by a remote response?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, browser-cache

I am currently building an app that queries the Indeed API for job postings. The user can successfully query and get a response. However, the data is not persisted if they, for example, view a job posting and then press the back button on their browser. How can I cache the JS response so a user can see their results without having to search again? I would imagine I would have to do some sort of caching but I don't know where to begin. I know there is a view helper method 'cache' but I don't think that is what I am looking for.

### jobs/index.html.haml

```
...snippet...

   .job-search-form
    = form_tag(jobs_search_path, method: "post", remote: true, id: 'job-search') do
      .row
        .col-md-6.job-search-keywords
          = text_field_tag :q,
                           nil,
                           :class => 'form-control job-query'

          = label_tag 'q', 'keywords or company'

          .jobs-by-indeed
            = link_to "Jobs", "http://www.indeed.com", tabindex: '-1'
            by
            = image_tag 'jobsearch.gif'

        .col-md-4.job-search-location
          = text_field_tag :l,
                           nil,
                           :class => 'form-control job-location'

          = label_tag 'l', 'city, state or zip code'

        .col-md-2
          #search-submission= submit_tag "Search", class: 'form-control', data: { disable_with: "Searching..." }
```

### jobs_controller.rb#search

```
  def search
    @jobs = @client.search(search_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

### jobs/search.js.erb

```
$('.job-search-results').html("<%= j render 'search_results', locals: @jobs %>");
```

Below is an animated gif that shows an empty page after returning from a job posting. Thanks in advance for any help.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After messing around with this for a bit, I found out that what I am doing isn't really supported by the HTTP standard. I was triggering a search using the post method when I should have been using the get method. I feel like this solution is a valid correct answer because it abides by the HTTP standard and seems to be the most reliable solution without implementing some sort of front end framework.

### jobs/index.html.haml

```
...snippet...

   .job-search-form
    = form_tag(jobs_search_path, method: :get, remote: true, id: 'job-search') do
      .row
        .col-md-6.job-search-keywords
          = text_field_tag :q,
                           nil,
                           :class => 'form-control job-query'

          = label_tag 'q', 'keywords or company'

          .jobs-by-indeed
            = link_to "Jobs", "http://www.indeed.com", tabindex: '-1'
            by
            = image_tag 'jobsearch.gif'

        .col-md-4.job-search-location
          = text_field_tag :l,
                           nil,
                           :class => 'form-control job-location'

          = label_tag 'l', 'city, state or zip code'

        .col-md-2
          #search-submission= submit_tag "Search", class: 'form-control', data: { disable_with: "Searching..." }
```

renamed `jobs/search.js.erb` to `jobs/index.js.erb`

Answer (score 0):

If you want a caching sort of thing on the client side you can use this in your js

```
localStorage.setItem("key",data);
```